Getting "Invalid nonce" error when authenticating user via Okta and LinkedIn OpenID integration
I've configured Okta as my authentication provider and set up OpenID IDP with a LinkedIn app. When attempting to authenticate a user, the process redirects to the LinkedIn sign-in page and then to the Okta redirect URI, but I encounter an "Invalid nonce" error. I've included a screenshot of the error for reference. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?


Here's what I've done so far:
Checked scopes on Okta side: I've configured the scopes as openid, email, and profile.
Cross-checked authorization endpoints on Okta side:
Issuer: <https://www.linkedin.com>
Authorization endpoint: <https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization>
Token endpoint: <https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken>
JWKS endpoint: <https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/openid/jwks>
Userinfo endpoint: <https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo>
Additionally, I've ensured that my LinkedIn app permissions include "Share on LinkedIn" and "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect."

